# Meaning of "sleep" and "shave it through on the grub"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, slang, literature

I read in "The White Silent" of Jack London and see this sentence

> 'Only one day. *We can shave it through on the grub*, and I might knock over a moose.'

I do not understand meaning of *'we can shave it through on the grub'*. Do you explain clearly for me?

And Jack London use 'sleep' in this story, example:

> I'm a gone man, Kid. Three or four **sleeps** at the best. You've got to go on. You must go on! Remember, it's my wife, it's my boy—O God! I hope it's a boy! You can't stay by me—and I charge you, a dying man, to pull on.

So what mean of 'sleep' in this context?

Comment: I'd say ***shave [it] through*** could be a deliberately non-standard mangling of ***to scrape by / through*** intended to imply that the speaker  is at least *somewhat* dialectally isolated from mainstream speech patterns. Although there are quite a few instances of ***shave it through*** in Google Books, *every single one of them* is the exact quote cited here. It has no currency to speak of. I suspect the same might apply to ***I charge you ... to pull on*** - normal speakers don't use ***charge*** like that in conversational contexts, and ***pull on*** would normally be ***push on***.

Comment: This is really two different questions. It would be better if you posted them separately.

Comment: _Charge_ in the sense of _entrust someone with a task_ is old-fashioned and formal, but Jack London was writing in the 19th century and the speaker is obviously making a highly emotional appeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of **shave it** (same structure as 'do it' and '[We've] made it!', with crypto-referential 'it') is 'just about manage to ...' (survive / win the match / pass the exam ...).

I've not yet found the expression in a dictionary, but the related  'It was a close shave' is a well-known metaphor. 'X just about shaved it' is used informally in the UK at least to mean '[Side] X were just about the better side [and thus deserved to / their win]':

> "The score was irrelevant. Both sides wanted to win the match and
>   Oldham probably just about shaved it...." [[The Bolton
>   News_2001](https://www.theboltonnews.co.uk/news/5999439.no-worries-for-leigh/)]

Another example showing a close victory / achievement / outperformance / overcoming:

> He was brilliant; so was she. I've watched the favourite & although
>   Olivia Coleman was very good, I think Close just about shaved it for
>   me, great acting. [tidied]
>   [[twitter.com/hashtag/thewife](https://twitter.com/hashtag/thewife?src=hash&vertical=default&lang=fr)]

'We can shave it through on the grub' is thus 'We can just about manage [until the situation improves] on the food we've got at the moment.'

.......

**Sleeps** here is a metonym/synecdoche for *days*, days travelling. It obviously connotes more of the lifestyle being enjoyed/endured than the unmarked term 'days'.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sleep) gives the broadened senses:

> **sleep** ...
>
> 3a : a period spent sleeping
>
> b : night
>
> c : a day's journey

There is a famous canyon in the Southwest (arguably just about) of the United States called 'Ten Sleep Canyon' [[TravelWyoming](https://www.travelwyoming.com/listing/ten-sleep/ten-sleep-canyon)] (though it took the coach my wife and I were on less than a morning to negotiate).

Comment: Note that "grubbing for food" has the meaning of "scrounging", and may trace back to the practice of eating grubs.  I suspect that the author's intended meaning was that they could eek by for several days just eating foods they could find.  Of course, "knock over a moose" referred to somehow killing a moose for food.

Comment: @HotLicks - c. 1300, "dig in the ground," from hypothetical Old English *grybban, *grubbian, from West Germanic *grubbjan (source also of Middle Dutch grobben, Old High German grubilon "to dig, search," German grübeln "to meditate, ponder"), from PIE *ghrebh- (2) "to dig, bury, scratch" (see grave (n.)). Transitive sense "dig up by the roots" is from 1550s. Related: Grubbed; grubbing. (Etymonline)